# Run PHP script on every page load in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've created a hit counted in PHP that saves into a database and the script currently only runs when you navigate to the page where the script is, what I'm wanting to do it make it so every time my page loads it runs the script. I belive I have to do this in the .htaccess file bit i'm not to sure on how.

Here is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.giantnodes\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.giantnodes.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) to run a script every time before the requested script runs.

You can set that in the `php.ini` file or in the `.htaccess` file.

For `.htaccess` you can add something like this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/your/file.php"
```

Comment: Now this is better than mine for his case! +1

Comment: Edit, Nevermind:  I guess auto_prepend_file acts the same as require at the top of each script.  Looks pretty useful.

Comment: That's what I did but when ever I did it I got a internal error here is the path that I'm using

php_value auto_prepend_file "public_html/admin/assets/php/hitcounter.php"

Comment: @Jordan check your error log but you should use the full path to the file or at the very least exclude public_html.  This is the context of the script that is called, the same as if you used require/include in that script so I doubt public_html is the right directory.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering, this only works for requested PHP files. _It does not run if requesting a different type of file from the server._